# how to create a module without dti interface?

Tags: python, pygears

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
from pygears.typing import Uint
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen

@gear
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

a = Uint[8]
b = Uint[8]
inst = add(a, b)

hdlgen('/add', outdir='sv')
```

It seem that hdlgen generates a module with dti if I use `Intf`. I only want to generate codes like this:

```
module add (
input logic [7:0] a, 
input logic [7:0] b,
output logic [7:0] dout
);

assign dout = a + b;

endmodule
```

Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PyGears is designed for dataflow systems and it is a requirement for each gear (i.e. module) to have DTI interfaces as its inputs and outputs which eases composability of the gears and control of the system.

However, if you are using HLS, you can implement arbitrary logic inside a single gear where only input and output ports have to be DTI.

```py
@gear
async def async_example(a, b) -> b'a+b':
    # Unpack the DTI interfaces
    async with a as aa, b as bb:
        # Custom logic
        if aa < bb:
            yield aa + bb
        else:
            yield aa + 1
```